# Most portable way to use mprotect() on allocated memory

Tags: c, posix, standards, mmap, mprotect

I was wondering if there is a portable way to dynamically allocate memory and then restrict read/write access to a portion of this memory, e. g. using the POSIX function [`mprotect()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mprotect.html). I can think of the following approaches:

1. Allocate memory using [`mmap()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mmap.html), i. e. `mmap(NULL, len, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0)`: Here, the memory protection flags can already be given in the initial allocation call, and can optionally be modified later using `mprotect()`.
   **Problem:** [`MAP_ANONYMOUS` is not specified by POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap#File-backed_and_anonymous), although it’s supposedly supported by [“almost all”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap#File-backed_and_anonymous) or [“most” systems](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html).
2. Apparently, [using `mmap()` on `/dev/zero` is an alternative to `MAP_ANONYMOUS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap#Example_of_usage_under_the_C_programming_language). This would make the `mmap()` call itself fully POSIX-compatible, but it seems that this behavior is not necessarily more portable than `MAP_ANONYMOUS` (apparently does not work on Mac OS X/macOS).
3. Allocate memory using [`aligned_alloc()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/aligned_alloc) (or [`posix_memalign()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_memalign.html)) and use `mprotect()`.
   **Problem:** The behavior of [`mprotect()` according to POSIX is only specified for memory obtained via `mmap()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mprotect.html), although at least [“on Linux, it is always permissible to call `mprotect()` on any address in a process’s address space (except for the kernel vsyscall area)”](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mprotect.2.html#NOTES).

So from the standards point of view, the problem is that `mprotect()` is only specified in combination with `mmap()`, but there is no standard that actually specifies dynamic memory allocation with `mmap()`. It seems that option (1.) is the most portable. Is there another approach that works on more systems (or, even better, is actually specified by a standard)?

Comment: Portably, you can only operate on entire pages of memory.  Did you read this part of [the POSIX `mprotect()` page](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mprotect.html):  "The `mprotect()` function shall change the access protections to be that specified by `prot` for **those whole pages containing any part of the address space of the process** starting at address `addr` and continuing for `len` bytes."

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yes, I’m aware. My problem is how to allocate memory in the first place that `mprotect()` is allowed to operate on.

Comment: Why not use a shared memory segment? mprotect is for *memory objects*...

Comment: Well since mprotect is only specified for memory obtained via mmap, I suppose you should not ask how to portably use mprotect, you should ask how to portably allocate memory with mmap.

Comment: @user253751 I suppose so, but I decided to focus on `mprotect()` because I want to do memory protection, and `mmap()` is just a complicating detail on that path. Moreover, perhaps there is another way (which I don’t know about) that doesn’t directly use `mmap()`, but is specified to be equivalent to using `mmap()`. And finally, I had already somewhat given up on strict POSIX compliance when writing this question, so I was prepared to potentially accept answers which use `mprotect()` without `mmap()`.

Answer (score 0):

How about shared memory object via `shm_open`? `shm_open` returns a file descriptor which can be mapped by `mmap` and therefore `mprotect`(ed).

Comment: I wasn’t really familiar with shared memory objects – this could be an option, although it feels a bit like abusing shared memory objects for something they were not designed for, with a bunch of unnecessary overhead. I really just want to get an equivalent of `malloc()` (i. e. simple memory allocation local to a single process) which I can use with `mprotect()` (or something equivalent). But perhaps this is the closest POSIX-only approximation?

Comment: Actually, I don’t want to share memory across processes. My goal is a rudimentary form of memory safety, i.e. to prevent writes or reads to parts of already-allocated memory which are known not to be accessed at certain points, [similar to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1687415). Kind of like an `assert` statement.

Comment: Also, `shm_open()` has its own compatibility complications related to the `name` that has to be given to the object. This kind of loops back to a similar problem that is present with `mmap()`: Ideally, I would want an *anonymous* shared memory object, but just as with `mmap()`, such a thing is not specified by POSIX. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55704758) and its accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55711740) have a nice explanation of the details.

Comment: Yes, i realized that and my information about `mprotect` was wrong, that's why i deleted my comment (too late to edit it). The only ways to protect memory would be the use of `const` (yes can be cast away but not without a warning by the compiler) or like the user 'Wernsey' suggests in your link, by encapsulation, a getter method to a hidden array.

Comment: Unfortunately, the “hidden” array wouldn’t protect against the class of errors I’m trying to catch (such as buffer overflows).

Comment: Well, there is nothing wrong about the extensive use of `const`.